# Анимированный график в Plotly на Scattergl

Tags: python, plotly

Бьюсь второй день над тем, чтобы заставить работать анимированный график, используя `Scattergl`. Обычный `Scatter` работает, работает у меня и Scatter3d. Первый я не могу использовать, потому что у меня десятки и сотни тысяч точек, мне нужно аппаратное ускорение. Вот простой пример проблемы:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
 
fig = go.Figure()
 
fig.add_trace(go.Scattergl(x=[4, 2, 56, 3, 1], y=[2, 35, 2, 12, 5], mode="markers"))
 
frames = [
    go.Frame(name=0, data=go.Scattergl(x=[12, 4, 1, 6, 5], y=[4, 2, 5, 45, 23], mode="markers")),
    go.Frame(name=1, data=go.Scattergl(x=[8, 6, 5, 3, 8], y=[9, 7, 6, 4, 11], mode="markers"))
]
 
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[dict(type="buttons",
                                    buttons=[dict(label="►", method="animate", args=[None, {"fromcurrent": True}])])])
 
fig.frames = frames
 
fig.show()
```

Проблема в том, что кадры не отображаются (хотя `hovertemplate` меняется), не отрисовываются новые точки. Если поменять `Scattergl` на `Scatter`, то всё работает.

Comment: Хм, интересно. У меня тоже не работает, я попробовал. Может там как-то этот WebGL нужно инициализировать предварительно? А что касается тысяч точек, то может `Holoviews` использовать, он вроде специально заточен на отображение очень, очень больших данных. Не знаю, правда, что там с анимациями.

Comment: Да беда в том, что у меня моё ПО построено на использовании Plotly. Там уже всё автоматизировано. Большинство графиков в 3D и я использую Scatter3D и он отлично работает, используя WebGL. Даже не думал, что с 2D могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: Сейчас пришёл к тому, что в Scattergl не работает именно метод animate. Если например использовать update и слайдер, то всё работает. Но это накладывает на меня ограничения по работе с легендой, hovertemplate и т.д...